# min function on pyspark pandas is too slow

Tags: pandas, pyspark, min

I have a scenario where I am reading 200 million records from Azure blob into pyspark pandas dataframe, executing multiple column operations (data type change, renaming of columns, calculations with the column) on the df, and then fetching the minimum value of a specific column.

This operation takes around 7 minutes, whereas a distinct operation on any column takes only a few seconds. Also, if I eliminate all the column operations and just take the minimum of that column, it takes only 13 seconds.

Please let me know if there is a way I can optimize my code to bring down the execution time of min with all the column operations.

Comment: can you share some code?

Answer (score 0):

You've mentioned that a group of functions take a certain about of time and said its too slow (fair enough). But you should try to find the exact thing slowing down your application. My assumption would be your calculations (as the others are optimised inbuilt functions and you haven't shown your calculations). Double check that theory and let us know what you find

Comment: Sure, I will analyze and let you know. but I was wondering the distinct of columns with the same set of operations takes only few seconds, whereas min function takes 7 minutes. I was trying to understand how min function works differently from distinct in the backend.

Comment: If its specifically the min function could you share the code that you've used? thanks

Comment: I analyzed the code and found that it is the data type change that is slowing down the operation.
df['Col1'] = df['Col1'].str.replace(',', '').replace('$', '').astype(np.float64)
df['Col2'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Col2']).astype(np.datetime64)
This the code that is written for data type change. Is there a way to improve the performance here.